# Calling Swift's readline to the same variable twice ignores the second call

Tags: swift, null, variable-assignment, readline

I'm reading user input from command line, checking if it's a valid file path and—if it's not—asking the user to try again.

In case the user input is `nil`, it should be treated as any other incorrect input the first time, letting the user enter a new value, but the second time that `nil` is entered, the program should force quit.

(I assume that a `nil` value is something a user won’t enter on purpose so if it happens more than twice I assume something has gone wrong and quit the program to avoid a never-ending loop asking for new input. This may or may not be a good way to do it but that doesn’t affect the question.)

The problem is that `readLine()` doesn’t ask for user input the second time it is called after if it has received an end-of-line input (which yields the `nil` value). (End-of-line can be input with ^D.)

This means the function where `readLine()` is located automatically returns `nil` because that’s the latest value of the variable that receives the `readLine()`.

**Questions**

1. Shouldn’t `readLine()` be called no matter what value the receiving variable already has?
2. If so, why isn't the user asked for input when `nil` has been input once?

This is the code:

```
import Foundation

/**
    Ask the user to provide a word list file, check if the file exists. If it doesn't exist, ask the user again.
 */
func askUserForWordList() -> String? {
    print("")
    print("Please drag a word list file here (or enter its path manually), to use as basis for the statistics:")

    var path = readLine(stripNewline: true) // THIS IS SKIPPED IF "PATH" IS ALREADY "NIL".

    return path
}

/**
    Check the user input // PROBABLY NOT RELEVANT FOR THIS QUESTION
 */
func fileExists(filePath: String) -> Bool {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

/**
    Get the file from the user and make sure it’s valid.
 */
func getFilePathFromUser() throws -> String {

    enum inputError: ErrorType {
        case TwoConsecutiveEndOfFiles
    }
    var correctFile = false
    var path: String? = ""
    var numberOfConsecutiveNilFiles = 0

    repeat {
        // Check that the user did not enter a nil-value (end-of-file) – if they did so two times in a row, terminate the program as this might be some kind of error (so that we don't get an infinite loop).
        if numberOfConsecutiveNilFiles > 1 { // FIXME: entering ^D once is enough to end the program (it should require two ^D). Actually the problem seems to be in function "askUserForWordList()".
            throw inputError.TwoConsecutiveEndOfFiles
        }

        path = askUserForWordList()

        if path == nil {
            numberOfConsecutiveNilFiles += 1
        } else {
            numberOfConsecutiveNilFiles = 0

            correctFile = fileExists(path!)

            if !correctFile {
                print("")
                print("Oops, I couldn't recognize that file path. Please try again.")
            }
        }
    } while !correctFile

    return path!
}

// This is where the actual execution starts

print("")
print("=== Welcome to \"Word Statistics\", command line version ===")
print("")
print("This program will give you some statistics for the list of words you provide.")
do {
    let path = try getFilePathFromUser()
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
    exit(-46) // Using closest error type from http://www.swiftview.com/tech/exitcodes.htm (which may not be standard at all. I could, however, not find any "standard" list of exit values).
}
```

**Notes**

- When entering any other non-valid path (any string, even an empty one (just press Enter), the loop works as intended.
- Originally `path` in the `askUserForWordList()` function was declared as a constant (`let path = readLine(stripNewline: true)`) but I changed it to a `var` since it’s supposed to be updated everytime the function is called. However, this didn’t affect how the program works.
- I tried declaring `path` separately on the line before calling `readLine()`, which made no difference.
- I tried skipping the `path` variable completely and let the `askUserForWordList()` function return the `readLine()` result directly (`return readLine(stripNewline: true)`). This made no difference.
- I skipped the `askUserForWordList()` function all together and moved the code asking for user input into the ”main” code of the function "getFilePathFromUser()", but that didn’t change anything.

  Modified code:

  ```
  func getFilePathFromUser() throws -> String {

      enum inputError: ErrorType {
          case TwoConsecutiveEndOfFiles
      }
      var correctFile = false
      var path: String? = ""
      var numberOfConsecutiveNilFiles = 0

      repeat {
          // Check that the user did not enter a nil-value (end-of-file) – if they did so two times in a row, terminate the program as this might be some kind of error (so that we don't get an infinite loop).
          if numberOfConsecutiveNilFiles > 1 { // FIXME: entering ^D once is enough to end the program (it should require two ^D). Actually the problem seems to be in function "askUserForWordList()".
              throw inputError.TwoConsecutiveEndOfFiles
          }

          // MODIFIED – This code was previously located in "askUserForWordList()"
          print("")
          print("Please drag a word list file here (or enter its path manually), to use as basis for the statistics:")

          path = readLine(stripNewline: true)

          // END OF MODIFICATION

          if path == nil {
              numberOfConsecutiveNilFiles += 1
          } else {
              numberOfConsecutiveNilFiles = 0

              correctFile = fileExists(path!)

              if !correctFile {
                  print("")
                  print("Oops, I couldn't recognize that file path. Please try again.")
              }
          }
      } while !correctFile

      return path!
  }
  ```

Comment: Regarding the `exit(-46)`, Swift exit codes are the same as in C, so the only "standard" values are 0 (`EXIT_SUCCESS`) and 1 (`EXIT_FAILURE`). If you intend to exit anyways, I'd suggest using `fatalError()` instead, as it outputs the file and line number of the originating crash which helps with debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readLine()` returns `nil` if (and only if) the standard input file descriptor has reached end-of-file. This happens (for example) when reading the input
from a tty, and `Ctrl-D` (the ["end-of-transmission character"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character#Meaning_in_Unix)) is entered as the first character on a line.

All subsequent `readLine()` calls then return `nil` as well, there is no
way detect that "Ctrl-D was entered twice".
In other words, once the standard input is in the end-of-file condition
you cannot read any data from it anymore. If your programs *requires*
more data then you can only report an error, e.g.

```
guard let path = readLine(stripNewline: true) else {
    throw InputError.UnexpectedEndOfFile
}
```